# If the equation $\frac{ c^n - a^n+b^n+ d^n}{ab-cd} = z$ , then is it possible to prove that $\frac{d^n}{ab-cd} < z$ for all $n\ge3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let us consider $a<b<c$ such that $(a+b)=(c+d)$ and $n\ge3$.

It is possible to derive the values of $z$ for $n=3,\,4,\,5,\,6,\dots$ as follows

$$\begin{split}
z& = 3 (a+b)\\
&= 4 (a+b)^2 - 2 (ab+cd)\\
&= 5 (a+b)^3 - 5 (a+b) (ab+cd)\\
&= 6 (a+b)^4 - 9 (a+b)^2 (ab+cd) + 2[ (ab)^2+(abcd)+(cd)^2]
\end{split}$$
to make it simple say

$(a+b)=(c+d)=t$, $ab=u$, $cd=v$ then
$$\begin{split}
z &= 7 t^5 - 14 t^3 (u+v) + 7t (u^2+uv+v^2)\\
&  = 8 t^6 - 20 t^4 (u+v) + 16t^2(u^2+uv+v^2) - 2(u^3+u^2v+uv^2+v^3)\\
&       = 9 t^7 - 27 t^5 (u+v) + 30t^3(u^2+uv+v^2) - 9t(u^3+u^2v+uv^2+v^3)
\end{split}$$
and so on..,

Please note coefficients are interlinked for subsequent powers.
is it possible to prove without computation that

$d^n / (ab-cd) < z$ for $n\ge3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to proving:

$$\frac{c^n-a^n+b^n}{ab-cd}>0$$

For $n \geq 3$

If $0<a<b<c$ and $a+b=c+d$

(1) If $\frac{x}{y} > 0$ then either both $x$ and $y$ are positive or they both are negative.

Let's start,

For $n \geq 1$: $c^n+b^n \geq c^n > a^n$ hence:

$$c^n+b^n > a^n$$

$$c^n-a^n+b^n >0$$

(The above argument only works if we take $a,b,c$ positive) By (1) we must only prove :

$$ab-cd>0$$

But $ab>cd$ always holds [If $a+b=c+d$ and $0<a<b<c$ then is it true $ab>cd$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856470/if-ab-cd-and-0abc-then-is-it-true-abcd) given our restrictions, proofs are in the link.

Still as this is only my answer, it's only fair I provide you with a proof that is not copied from the links.Getting ideas from the link, I provide you with this proof that does not involve $a,b,c$ bieng positive.

First:

$$a+b-c=d=a+(b-c)<a$$

Hence,

$$\text{min}(a,b,c,d)=d$$

Furthermore we have:

$$ab-dc=a(c+d-a)-dc=ac+a(d-a)-dc=ac-dc-a(a-d)=c(a-d)-a(a-d)=(c-a)(a-d)>0$$

Hence your inequality always hold for $n \geq 1$ because both the denominator and numerator of:

$\frac{c^n-a^n+b^n}{ab-cd}$

Are positive, implying:

$$\frac{d^n}{ab-cd}=z-\frac{c^n-a^n+b^n}{ab-cd}<z$$

That's if we took $a,b,c$ positive. The proof I provided shows that $ab-cd>0$ hold even if $a,b,c,d$ are not positive. Hence if we take negative $a,b,c,d$ and an even $n$ it is possible that $c^n+b^n<a^n$ and hence the inequality  won't hold. For example see $-3<-2<-1$, then :

$$(-1)^4+(-2)^4<(-3)^4$$

And hence your inequality won't work.