# If $a+b=c+d$ and $0<a<b<c$ then is it true $ab>cd$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

If $a+b=c+d$ and $0<a<b<c$ then is it true $ab>cd$?

This is the only thing I know:

$\text{min}(a,b,c,d)=d$ as $d=a+(b-c)<a$.

So it might be true that the inequality holds.

I've tried substituting in $a+b-c$ for $d$ to get no where. Also where working with positive integers.

Thanks.

Comment: Typo in the title: I think you want $ab>cd$

Comment: Yes that's what I've wanted thanks. @MathematicsStudent1122

Comment: First find out what the inequality _means_ for d. You've done that. Then you need to figure out: If you know the sum x+y and the sum is fixed, how large can x*y be? In what situation would the product be largest, and when would it be smaller? Then tell us what you know about a,b and c,d and apply what you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let $n=\frac{a+b}2$(which is the same as $\frac{c+d}2$), $m_1=\frac{b-a}2$ and $m_2=\frac{c-d}2$. Then $0<m_1<m_2$ and we have
$$
ab=(n-m_1)(n+m_1)=n^2-m_1^2\\
cd=(n-m_2)(n+m_2)=n^2-m_2^2
$$
We see that $ab$ is the bigger of the two, since $-m_1^2>-m_2^2$.

Comment: How do you know $m_1 \leq m_2$?

Comment: Because of $d<a<b<c$. It's simply a statement of the fact that the distance between $c$ and $d$ is greater than the distance between $a$ and $b$. More accurately, $$m_2=m_1+\frac{c-b}2+\frac{a-d}2$$and both those extra terms are positive.

Comment: Ok thanks mind if I use that to edit my first ever answer on this site, I'll include a link to your answer. @Arthur

Comment: It's a different question. In my first question I "proved" what you proved but wrongly, in part of my answer. If I include your answer in part of my proof than my answer will become more correct @Arthur see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316695/if-the-equation-frac-cn-anbn-dnab-cd-z-then-is-it-possible-to. I would like to fix my answer even though it is a year or so old.

Comment: Oh, right. That's no problem at all.

Comment: This is form of statement geometric mean = $\sqrt {xy}\ge (x+y)/2$ = arithmetic mean (for x,y positive that is equivalent to $(x-y)^2 >0\ge 0$-- square both sides, multiply both by four, subtract LHS from both sides.)  The further away from the mean the more uneven it becomes.  (If the mean is m. Then $m^2 > m^2 - r^2 = (m-r)(m+r) $ obviously the further two points are from the mean the larger the difference.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{eqnarray}ab\!-\!cd &=& a(b\!-\!c)+c(\color{#c00}{a\!-\!d})\\ &=& a(b\!-\!c)+c(\color{#c00}{c\!-\!b})\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{a+b = c+d} \\ &=& (c\!-\!a)(c\!-\!b) > 0\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ c > b > a\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Thanks this one is really clear!

Comment: @Ahmed Note that I didn't use $\, a > 0,\,$ only $\,c > a,b,\,$ so it will also work negative values too.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is obviously true if $d\le0$, since $a,b,c\gt0$ implies $ab\gt0\ge cd$ when $d\le0$.

If $d\gt0$, write $a=d(1+A)$, $b=d(1+B)$, and $c=d(1+C)$.  The assumption $a+b=c+d$ becomes $A+B=C$, and the assumption $0\lt a\lt b\lt c$ becomes $0\lt A\lt B\lt C$. Then, since $AB\gt0$ we have

$$ab=d^2(1+A)(1+B)=d^2(1+A+B+AB)\gt d^2(1+A+B)=d^2(1+C)=cd$$

Answer (score 1):

$$0\lt a\lt b\lt c\Rightarrow a+b\lt a+c=c+d+(a-d)\Rightarrow 0\lt a-d \iff d\lt a$$ It follows $$0\lt d\lt a\lt b\lt c$$
Put $$a=d+h_1\\b=d+h_2\\c=d+h_3$$ where $0\lt h_1\lt h_2\lt h_3$ and $h_1+h_2=h_3\iff a+b=c+d$.

Hence $$ab-cd=d(h_1+h_2-h_3)+h_1h_2=h_1h_2\gt 0$$ Thus $$\color{red}{ab\gt cd}$$

Answer (score 1):

If the sums are the same, the product is maximized for positive variables when they are closer together.  You can formalize using Karamata, for e.g.
$$ab > cd \iff \log(a)+\log(b) > \log(c) + \log (d)$$

Here is is easy to note $\log t$ is strictly concave and $(c, d) \succ (a, b)$.